# Damped Track constraint on bone lags

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, constraints

So basically if you use a Damped Track constraint + Limit Distance constraint to move a bone with another one there is these strange bugs where the mesh doesn't move with it.

Especially when creating an animation this is a real problem because what happens is that you set up the keyframe for the thing and the mesh will move like it 1 frame later. At the actual keyframe it will have the position of the frame before and so on.

Do you guys know this issue and maybe got a solution?

EDIT: Well, I managed the animation somehow.
When you move the bone once it will reset the weird position then you can cancel the move. Yet there is some strange issues with the positions, I don't even know how they emerge. Plus I don't know if the animation will run correctly in any situation or if there will be these slight position changes occurring and this sucks.

a) Maybe someone can tell me that the animation runs correctly when for example used multiple times and with interpolation to other animations in the bge *hoping*.

b) Maybe fix this issue Blender guys, not pointing a finger.

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue where you have problems with dependecies.  What is the target of your constraints?  Does it in any way depend on a bone in the same armature?  Separate these bones to different armatures, as object dependcies work on an object-by-object basis, not a bone-by-bone basis.  (Although yes, it is irritating, and potentially fixable by Blender devs.)

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue, check the constraints loading order, if you also have copy rotation on that lagging bone, make sure it's on top of the damped track constraints.