# Object locations totally messed up

Tags: armature, bones

this will be hard to explain clearly, so i'll go through step by step.
make a robot, assign various robot parts with specific origins.
Learn about bones, give it bones, move it around by dragging the armature in the viewport.

I''ve had some odd problems with animating [problem1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/196855/blender-2-8-animation-render-output-does-not-match-editor-bone-fail) [probably the same problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197368/animated-object-disconnects-and-floats-around-should-not-disconnect-and-float-a)

so i tried checking the origins of some of the parts. as soon as i did things like 'origin to geometry' or even 'editmode-selectall-snapcursortoselected' these parts would fly over near the centre of the viewport.

so i 'applied all transforms' and look at this mess
what w see here is, the bones have broken free from their meshes, the origins are kinda random but mostly over toward the right of the pic, the feet (silver ball things) have run off, the legs are a broken mess, the gun has fallen off.

spooky action at a distance stuff. i have entangled worlds
[image]

what the hell is happening
how did it get so bad
is there a reasonable way to fix this rather than rebuild piece by piece?

Comment: hard to say, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Cheers mate, I've 'lightened' the file a lot and marked the offending bits in yellow. 
[link](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8E2kgAKD/)

Comment: I don't see what you're talking about, but I'm not sure about your rigging. First thing I would put all my bones inside the same armature. Second thing I would create a foot bone that would be parented by the IK controller bone (the one currently called Right foot), and I wouldn't give the controller a Limit Distance constraint, that doesn't seem to work fine

Comment: pt 1 of 2
thanks for taking a look. 
I realise how messy my question is, becasue ive been working on it and after  so many iterations, ive forgotten what ive said.

I believe the underlying problem is the same, but what ive uploaded is a totally new armature with refinements in many ways.
BUT, the piston barrels still flick around when the robot moves.
I'm convinced that if we solve that, we solve all of my problems.
when you play the animation, robot will glide across in font of the camera. nothign else should happen, but you'll see the yellow piston barrels flicking.

Comment: pt 2 of 3
regarding your suggestions: I initially put all the bones in  the same armature, but when applying the damped track, i couldnt select the armature. I had incorrectly assumed that they had to be seperate armatures.

Comment: pt 3 of 3
I'll try all the suggestions, but dont understand the additional footbone. I think.. you want me to add another bone to the foot, maybe call it IK, take the ik off the current 'right foot' and apply it to the new IK bone, and then parent the 'right foot' to the IK bone? although its currently parented to the shin bone.

the min/max limits are to prevent the piston tube ripping out of the piston barrel if the legs move too far

Comment: might have an answer - https://blenderartists.org/t/wierd-random-dotted-line-connected-to-bone/568213/7

Comment: Piston problem! 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182934/damped-track-on-object-in-armature-moves-in-unexpected-and-irregular-way

Comment: so have you found your answer?

Comment: i saved at an inopportune time and both problems are now deeply integrated into the file. but i think i have both answers, it will just take a lot of work to unpick all the bits. might be faster to start all over

so, the flicking piston is because you cant have two objects trackign to eachother. workaround, is to add a child object right next to 'piston base' and have the piston tube target the child instead.

the feet thing is to do with that 'weird random line connected to bone' link above

but until i actually do the work, i cant fully confirm